# can't keep images side by side, btw i can't do bootstrap

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcSWt.png)I want to keep two images side by side and then do the same right below, total 4 different images button in one div, i also have called sub div for each image, but it looks fine when i keep it big, but whenever I am trying to view it in a mobile screen one of them stays in the left side and the remaining ones go to the right side, i have added a image of that>> https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcSWt.png

Comment: Read the SO posting guidelines.

Comment: i am new here  so i don't know what is so

Comment: SO = Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Post your code please, but in the mean time -

```
overflow:hidden;
```

On the parent, and:

```
float:left;
```

on the sub divs.

Comment: <!doctype html> <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <div id="navBar"> <div id="subDiv1" class="icon-bar five-up"> <a class="item"> <img src="a.png" class="i" > <label>Moblie Assist</label> </a> </div> <div id="subDiv2" class="icon-bar five-up"> <a class="item"> <img src="b.png" class="i"> <label>Security</label> </a> </div> <div id="subDiv3" class="icon-bar five-up"> <a class="item"> <img src="s.png" class="i" > <label>Service</label> </a> </div> <div id="subDiv4" class="icon-bar five-up"> <a class="item">....